ADRP instruction address resolution
I'm trying to read the documentation for the ADRP arm64 instruction and I'm not sure about one aspect. The best way is to show it in code:
ULONG64 uiAddr = 0xfffff80198964c08;    //Address of the following opcode
ULONG32 opcode = 0x900016d0;            //Opcode for the ADRP instruction to resolve

//Check if opcode is correct
if((opcode & 0x9F000000) != 0x90000000)
{
    //Bad opcode
    wprintf(L"Bad opcode for ADRP instruction: 0x%X\n", opcode);
    return -1;
}

ULONG64 imm;
imm = (opcode & 0x60000000) >> 29;
imm |= (opcode & 0x00FFFFE0) >> 3;

//Do I need to do this?
//uiAddr += sizeof(opcode);             //Advance PC by the size of the opcode

uiAddr += imm << 12;
uiAddr &= ~((0x1LL << 12) - 1);

ULONG uiReg = opcode & 0x1F;

wprintf(L"ADRP address resolution: x%u=0x%I64X\n", uiReg, uiAddr);

Is that how it works - do I need to advance PC by the size of the opcode?

You don't need to add the size. In arm64 PC points to the current instruction.
